# How can I get input radio elements to horizontally align in react [material-ui]?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

The radio group is always vertical listed in material-ui. Is there a way to horizontally align them? e.g. all radio button in one horizontal line.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Simply use the [`row` property](https://material-ui.com/api/form-group/#props):

```
<RadioGroup row><Radio /><Radio /></RadioGroup>
```

[`RadioGroup`](https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/#radiogroup) inherits from [`FormGroup`](https://material-ui.com/api/form-group/) so the properties of the `FormGroup` component are also available.

Another example, with labels:

```html
<RadioGroup aria-label="anonymous" name="anonymous" value={false} row>
  <FormControlLabel value="true" control={<Radio />} label="Yes" />
  <FormControlLabel value="false" control={<Radio />} label="No" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: The currently selected answer works and did receive my upvote. However, I think this should be selected answer because it's better aligned with the material UI documentation on how to horizontally align (make a row from) a group of child form inputs.

Comment: I love this answer!

Answer (score 24):

To render the radio buttons in a row:

```
<RadioButtonGroup style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
```

To reset sizing according to content:

```
<RadioButton style={{ width: 'auto' }} />
```

Comment: Doesn't work if your radio buttons are wrapped in a FormControlLabel. @HydraHatRack solution, on the other hand, does work.

Answer (score 10):

Simply add the prop ***row={true}*** on the RadioGroup control.

```
 <RadioGroup
      aria-label="Location"
      name="location"
      className={classes.group}
      value={location}
      onChange={handleChange}
      row={true}
      >
         <FormControlLabel value="company" control={<Radio />} label="Company" />
         <FormControlLabel value="home" control={<Radio />} label="Home" />
         <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
 </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as my answer above. <RadioGroup row /> is just using JSX shorthand for boolean props.

Answer (score 7):

For those who are still struggling, use this style:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    group: {
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'nowrap',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    }
});

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        <RadioGroup className={classes.group} ...>
    }

};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated and brittle when you can use the [`row` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680157/how-can-i-get-input-radio-elements-to-horizontally-align-in-react-material-ui/54163160#54163160).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to mention `row` in `<RadioGroup>`.
You can write your code like this:

```
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        <FormLabel >Lable</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup aria-label="overall_sal" name="Overall SAL" value={value} onChange={handleChange} row>
          <FormControlLabel value="low" control={<Radio />} label="Low" />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
```

Comment: Works like perfect Jay!

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet, but to add to what @lambdakris said: 
You may also need to add flexDirection: 'row'. The easiest way to make these changes instead of using the inline styles is to add your css to the styles object and class that material-ui already uses.

```
const styled = theme => ({
 formControl: {
                margin: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
                width: "100%", //parent of radio group
              },
       group: {
               flexDirection: 'row',
               justifyContent: 'space-around',
               }
             });
...........
<RadioButtonGroup className={classes.group}>
```

Comment: No need to complicate with flex. Use the [row prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680157/how-can-i-get-input-radio-elements-to-horizontally-align-in-react-material-ui/54163160#54163160).