# How to conditionally add a property in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, radio-group

I have a simple material UI RadioGroup code which i want to display conditionally in row and column, default mode is column, Below is my code

```
 <RadioGroup
  aria-label="gender"
  name="gender1"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
  <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
  <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Now in order to display it in row, i need to add one poperty `row` at `RadioGroup` like below

```
<RadioGroup
  row
  aria-label="gender"
  name="gender1"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
```

How can i just update one line conditionally? Here is codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-tr7f3?file=/demo.js:386-744)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get input radio elements to horizontally align in react \[material-ui\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680157/how-can-i-get-input-radio-elements-to-horizontally-align-in-react-material-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `isRow` state and use it's value to conditionally render RadioGroup as row or otherwise

```
const [isRow, setIsRow] = useState(true);
```

```
<RadioGroup
  row={this.state.isRow}
  aria-label="gender"
  name="gender1"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
```